# triangulatePoint opencv error

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
MatOfPoint2f normalizedTrackedPts = new MatOfPoint2f();
MatOfPoint2f normalizedBtstrapPts = new MatOfPoint2f();

//CamMat = cameraMatirx , discoeff
Imgproc.undistortPoints(getMatofPoint2fFromMatofKeyPoint(trackedFeatures), normalizedTrackedPts, camMat, new Mat());
Imgproc.undistortPoints(getMatofPoint2fFromMatofKeyPoint(btstrap_kp), normalizedBtstrapPts, camMat, new Mat());
//triangulate
Mat pt_3d_h = new Mat(4, trackedFeatures.rows() * trackedFeatures.cols(), CvType.CV_32FC1);
Calib3d.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, normalizedBtstrapPts, normalizedTrackedPts, pt_3d_h);
MatOfPoint3f pt_3d = new MatOfPoint3f();
Calib3d.convertPointsFromHomogeneous(pt_3d_h.t().reshape(4, 1), pt_3d);

for(int i  = 0; i < pt_3d.rows(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < pt_3d.cols(); j++)
    {
        //Debug.Log("1." + i + "/" + j + "/" + pt_3d.get(i, j)[0]);
        //Debug.Log("2." + i + "/" + j + "/" + pt_3d.get(i, j)[1]);
        //Debug.Log("3." + i + "/" + j + "/" + pt_3d.get(i, j)[2]);
        GameObject.Instantiate(cube, new Vector3((float)pt_3d.get(i, j)[0], (float)pt_3d.get(i, j)[1], (float)pt_3d.get(i, j)[2]), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

In Unity3D I use the `triangulatePoints` function. `trackedFeatures` is the first image Feature, and `btstrap` is the second image Feature. `camMat` is the camera's intrinsic matrix.  When I run this code in Unity3D, the cubes are in a  strange location.  Does anyone know what might be the problem?